# Teacher license laws

Tags: contract-law, north-carolina

As a teacher, am I bound to a 30-day notice if I never have signed a contract for the past 3 years for the position I am currently working? I have another job offer which requires me to give a 2-week notice. My current school district says I must give a 30-day notice or lose my license to teach. Was hired July 2016 (no contract). I requested a contract July 2018 and was never given one.

Comment: You definitely need to edit your question or the tags to add a jurisdiction.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. See [this page](https://stateboard.ncpublicschools.gov/legal-affairs/disciplinary-process/revoked-license) from the NC Board of Education, listing the 9 grounds for revocation of a license.

> 6. resignation from employment with a LEA without thirty work days' notice, except with the prior consent of the local superintendent;

A written contract is not required. I assume you were in fact working without a written contract in the prior year, that is, you were an employee.

Comment: Are we an Employment at Will state?

Comment: Yes, all states besides Montana are. That means they can fire you at will. They lists the recocations, and there are 3 prior cases of revocation for resignation.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So a district can revoke a license when an employee is NOT under contract. That's NC for you!